# Calculate average days between orders

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I would like to calculate the average days between several order dates from a table called Orders. For each CustomerID, what is the average days between orders. The sample table is as below ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fkyr.png)):

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders(CustomerID int, OrderDate datetime);

INSERT #Orders(CustomerID, OrderDate) VALUES
    (100,'20170114'),(100,'20170123'),(100,'20170129'),
    (101,'20170202'),(101,'20170212');
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT  CustomerID, AVG(OrderDate - PriorDate)
FROM (SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate
           , LAG(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate) as PriorDate
      FROM #Orders where CustomerID = 100)
```

However, this yields:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
>   
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 6):

Several issues:

- You are trying to take an average per customer, but you're not grouping by customer.
- Implicit math for datetimes (`OrderDate-PriorDate`) is not a good idea ([try that with date or datetime2](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)) - use `DATEDIFF`.
- Integer division will not give you an average like you think - try `SELECT 5/2;`. You need to convert at least one input to a decimal, either implicitly (`*1.0`) or explicitly (`CONVERT(), TRY_CONVERT(), CAST(), etc.`). Explicit allows you to control decimal places in some cases.
- `LAG()` was not complete - while the default is 1, I think it is good to be explicit that you want the previous row.
- The incorrect syntax error is actually coming from the end of the query - when you have something like `SELECT ... FROM (<subquery>)`, that subquery needs to be named, so you need to use something like `SELECT ... FROM (<subquery>) AS x;` for example.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  CustomerID, 
  AvgLag = AVG(CONVERT(decimal(7,2), DATEDIFF(DAY, PriorDate, OrderDate)))
FROM
(
  SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, PriorDate = LAG(OrderDate,1) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate)
  FROM #Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = 100
) AS lagged
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Results:

```
CustomerID    AvgLag
----------    ------
100           7.50
```

Of course, if you want the average for all customers, just leave out the `WHERE` clause. But if you really only ever want a single customer, you don't really need the customer in the output, so you can adjust the query a little bit to get rid of the `GROUP BY` (let's parameterize the customer ID while we're at it):

```
DECLARE @CustomerID int = 100;

SELECT AvgLag = AVG(Lag), CustomerID = @CustomerID -- you may not need this
FROM 
(
  SELECT Lag = CONVERT(decimal(7,2), DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(OrderDate,1) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate), OrderDate))
  FROM #Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
) AS Lagged;
```

Answer (score 5):

A way to simplify the query - if you only need the average lag between order dates - is to identify that you only need the dates of the first and last orders and the number of orders for each customer. If you have 11 orders for a customer, and a year between the first and the last order, the average is `365 / 10`.

```
SELECT 
  CustomerID, 
  AvgLag = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 
                    CONVERT(decimal(7,2), 
                            DATEDIFF(day, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate)))
                    / CONVERT(decimal(7,2), COUNT(*) - 1)
                ELSE NULL
           END
FROM #Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically the same as ypercube +1 (I did not see it)

```
select CustomerID
     , cast(DATEDIFF(dd, min(OrderDate), max(OrderDate)) as decimal) / (count(*) - 1) as [avgDayDelta], count(*)
from #Orders
group by CustomerID
having count(*) > 1
```